# "Like" function in a dataset stored in memory ( The same as like function in SQL )

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sql-like

Assume I have a large dataset and I want to run a "like" function in the dataset eg column - Name

Is there any way to run a like statement in a dataset?

Is it possible with ASP.NET?

I do not want to run a query to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dataTable.Select("Name like '%rob%'");
```

The LIKE statement is supported in the DataTable.Select function as documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the old link to the 1.1 version of the framework but it's supported in all later versions as well.

Comment: I think you need to use * instead of %

Comment: The "special" rule for the expressions is that they can't be used in the middle of a string, so 'te*xt' is not allowed in this format, but it would be in a normal sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You, my friend, are in need of some LINQ.  It is a generic query language which can, through the use of various providers, query SQL based data stores as well as in memory objects like lists.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use

```
YourDataTable.Select("Name LIKE 'surname*'");
```